# Reprojecting & CRS of Shapefile using sf Package in R

Tags: r, coordinates, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, r-sf

I am a new R user. I have a shapfile in R which I want to use to calculate the K nearest neighbor. Each polygon's centroid (Inside_X & Inside_Y) was calculated in arcmap (Example: X: 32570914 Y: 5791442). I used the `sf` package to get a CRS for my coordinates. Ideally, I would like to use the proj of my shapefile but it seems invalid in R. Below is my code. My problem is that the `knearneighbor` considers `knearneigh: coordinates are not geographical` and `st_is_longlat` gives`[FALSE]` even after setting a CRS. Please help.

```
>data<- readOGR (dsn = ".", layer ="My_Data")
>summary(data)

    Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
    Coordinates:
           min      max
    x 32568756 32641426
    y  5723944  5853056
    Is projected: TRUE 
    proj4string :
    [+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=0.9996 +x_0=32500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs]
    Data attributes:


>data.sf <- st_as_sf(data)


## Set CRS
>data.crs <- st_transform(data.sf, crs = 4839)
>st_crs(data.crs)

data.coord <- cbind(data.crs$INSIDE_X, data.crs$INSIDE_Y)

## K Nearest neighbor
>library(spdep)
>data.knn <- knearneigh(data.coord, k = 10, longlat = TRUE)

Warning message:
In knearneigh(data.coord, k = 10, longlat = TRUE) :
  knearneigh: coordinates are not geographical: longlat argument wrong
```

Comment: This is a *warning* that you've got `longlat=TRUE` but your coordinates are **NOT** in degrees of long-lat, because they are EPSG:4839. This is all explained in the help for knearneigh.

Answer (score 0):

Use EPSG 4326 instead of 4839, 4839 is project https://epsg.io/4839